# Run into error "empty beginning of file" when read.csv in R

Tags: r, read.csv

I have a csv file which has only one column and empty cells in the first couple cells. When I tried to read it into R with intention reading those blank lines as missing values, I run into the following error. Any help is appreciated!

```
Test = read.csv("test.csv", header = FALSE, blank.lines.skip = FALSE, nrows = 10)

Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
empty beginning of file
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try using `skip` or `data.table::fread`, it should be able to skip by it self.

Comment: I want to read blank lines as missing value.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem.  I made "csv" file with only one column (quotes around "csv" because there are no commas in it) and read it in with your code and it is fine including with NA.  So perhaps something funny in your file itself?  Have you looked at it with a text editor?

Comment: I tried again but it didn't work for me. Attached the excel and txt screenshot.

Comment: What does `readLines("test.csv")` return?

Comment: It only returns the non-missing values.....